# WPF: how to make Text in a custom control show up?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom button `MyButton` with a `Text` property defined as follows:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyButton));

public string Text
{
    get { return GetValue(TextProperty) as string; }
    set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
}
```

The `Text` property of `MyButton` is binded to an object's property:

```
<local:MyButton Text="{Binding Path=SomeString}"/>
```

I want the binded text to show up on a `TextBlock` inside `MyButton`, how to accomplish this?

this was my first bad attempt, modifying the setter

```
set
{
    SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    aTextBlock.Text = value.ToString(); //this is bad, from what i read
}
```

but then saw this at wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html

> Do not add any logic to these properties, because they are only called
>   when you set the property from code. If you set the property from XAML
>   the SetValue() method is called directly.

Any help is appreciated!

---

**UPDATE:** below is the xaml for `MyButton`

```
<UserControl ...>
    <Button HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Viewbox Stretch="Uniform" Grid.Column="0">
                <TextBlock x:Name="aTextBlock" Text="{Binding Path=Text}"/>
            </Viewbox>
            <Viewbox Grid.Column="1">
                <TextBlock Text="someText" />
            </Viewbox>
        </Grid>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

as shown, I tried to bind `Text` of `aTextBlock`, but that text never shows up; only "someText" from column 1 shows.

doing this as suggested by @Krishna

```
<TextBlock x:Name="aTextBlock" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
```

won't compile with the error

```
The member "Text" is not recognized or is not accessible.
```

Sorry I know this should be simple, but can't yet get it to work. I am not using template for this control. Thanks!

Comment: This is just a basic knowledge about WPF dependency property, try reading this first http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750428(v=vs.110).aspx That warning is correct, you should not add any custom code except `SetValue` (for setter) and `GetValue` (for getter).

Comment: Is this textblock inside your custom control? If it is you can simply do. <TextBlock Text={TemplateBinding Text}/> and this should  display the text property of your object

Comment: @Krishna yes, the TextBlock is inside my custom control; i've just posted the XAML. using `TemplateBinding` gives an error that prevents compilation (updated in question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Text` is the property of `UserControl` then you need to change binding source otherwise it will look for `Text` in current `DataContext`. You can do it either by `RelativeSource`

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=Text}"/>
```

or give `UserControl` some name

```
<UserControl ... x:Name="myUserControl">
```

and then use `ElementName` in you binding

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=Text}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the proper way, but it works for now. The `Text` of the `TextBlock` is changed via a call back method (learned from this [page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/10/15/building-a-custom-control-using-xaml-and-c.aspx))

In code behind of my user control:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyButton), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(TextPropertyChanged)));

public static FrameworkPropertyMetadata propertyMetadata =
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(TextPropertyChanged);

private static void TextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var btn = d as MyButton;
    btn.aTextBlock.Text = e.NewValue.ToString();
}
```